# how can I use php to search a txt or html file and pull out my tables I want to be able to pull everything inside of <table class="class1"> </table>

Tags: php, html

I have like 6 tables in a page and I want to be able to read that page and pull all the tables

everything in between

I guess I just need to do this 1 time and add a while to do it until the end of the page.

I know how to use the data from a variable later or use it from an array

but I have no clue on how to attempt to grab the data from my webpage

I am going to build a page from that data with a different style but re-using the same tables

Comment: in between table class="class1"       and end table

Comment: $startmatch = "<table =class1">";

Comment: $endmatch = "</table>";

Comment: $everythinginbetween = $result;

Comment: I have the pages all done and there are a lot of them I can read the whole page into  lets say

Comment: $page = file_get_contents("example.html");

Comment: I just need to be able to add table1 contents into let say $table

Comment: I understand - yes, this might work, but you will still have to go back and identify the data you want to pull out of $page on the original documents.  eg <td id=data51> data</td>  I think you may be better off pulling data *originally* from a data source, thus you can both post it and re-read it easily and consistently

Comment: Its the whole code I want in between the <table> </table> is there no way to grab everything

Comment: It is possible to do this with a straight read of the html file and then loop using string functions to separate out <table> data </table> etc, but this is going 50 miles to walk a foot and leaves yourself open to a ton of potential problems, the biggest of which is if *anything* ever changes in any of the pages.  If you are looking for just the table **code** and its data to re-use - why not create the tables as separate php files and include them?

Comment: That is what I will be doing with them when I pull I love includes but I have 3000+ files with my tables I want to pull them and build new includes using my info I have. it was a website I built back about 15 or more years ago. I will use php to pull the tables and rebuild them into include files I can add later to my website as needed

Comment: Ahh - I get it now -- I didn't understand that you weren't actually making the originals - sorry.  In that case I think the answer by @someOne below may be a very good starting point.

Comment: and thats all we had back then was tables lol so they are very simple but I dont know everything in php I have only been using it about 1 year and I have no clue what to use to pull things if I want everything in between tags like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, using the following requires you to "know" those tables having `class="class1"` attribute, which you should :)

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("path/to/filename.html");

$tables = $doc->getElementsByTagName("table");
$validClasses = array("class1", "class2", "class3", "class4", "class5", "class6");
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    if(in_array($table->getAttribute("class"), $validClasses)) {
        // Here begins your journey :)
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: There are class1 - class6 for the 6 different ones in each file is there a wild card I can use  so anythign starting with class will work

Answer (score 0):

*Now that I understand what you're after - someOne's answer seems a better starting point.

PHP can't 'pull' the data -- javascript can.  If you are looking to use the data on the server side with PHP, you will need to send it to that page through POST or GET.

There are a few ways to do that, but perhaps the easiest is to set up a PHP loop on the data page that sets an input inside each field that you wish to send to your php script.

I might do it sorta like this in pseudo code -

```
echo <form method=post action="phpreader.php">
for ($x = 0 ; $ < $tables; $x++){
   echo <table>
   echo  <tr><td> $data <input type=hidden name='data'.$x value = $data> </td></tr> 
  echo </table>
}
echo </form>
```

In the loop, you can put in as many table elements as you need and then attach the data to a form.

This will display your data programatically and also set it up to be send for post at the same time.  You will need something to trigger this to go to post.  Could be a Submit button, or javascript.

This could work, but I would maybe re-think your program method.  If you are displaying this data to begin with, it has to come from somewhere.  Might be a better way forward to pull the data from a database, display in the tables, and then you can re-pull the same data using the same query on your phpreader page.